# Can someone explain the use of Autofindviews nuget in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, nuget-package

What is the use of Autofindviews nuget in Xamarin.Android project?

I have seen few references saying it creates autogenerated code of layout files.

Is that nuget still in use. if so, is it compatible with Android latest sdks.

Can someone explain.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: it was last updated in 2017, so the answer seems fairly evident

Comment: @Jason Thanks for your reply. In [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFindViews/) I could see the framework monoandorid10, Does that mean it will support Android10. Could you please clarify me on this?